# How to subscribe to a FCM topic from a web client?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to subscribe to a FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) topic from the front end (web) of an Angular application.

From what I've learned from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging) and [here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/fcm-topic-notifications-angularfire-and-callable-functions), it looks like subscription to topics can't be done via web from the front end. The client should send a token and a topic to the server, then the server should request the subscription to FCM.

I'd like to know if there's a way I can securely subscribe to topics directly via web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it can be done client side

```
this.push.subscribe(
  'your Topic',
  () => {
    console.log('success');
  },
  e => {
    console.log('error:', e);
  }
);
```

more information

> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md
>
> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push

this is related your topic

> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-push-notification-topic-subscription/95523/6

Comment: Are you sure it can be done from a web client? If so, can you explain what should be installed and imported?

Comment: using same libry you can do it  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: What should I install? phonegap-plugin-push, @ionic-native/push or both?

Comment: you have to install both for IOnic

Comment: I'm working in an Angular project. Do I need to convert it to an Ionic project?

Comment: I used this:

``import 'phonegap-plugin-push';``

But it shows this:

``Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'phonegap-plugin-push' in...``

Comment: The question asked is not for ionic, this answer is for ionic client

Comment: this solution not work in angular , question asked  how to implement in angular